# Overlapping Properties for WMI Search?

Tags: c#, wmi

I am writing an application that stores disk objects for a computer as well as logical partitions for each disk. I am remotely using WMI and (specifically) a ManagementObjectSearch to query computers on my domain. I am wondering if there are any properties between the WMI classes Win32_DiskDrive and Win32_LogicalDrive that would allow me to check whether a partition belongs to a specific disk or not. I can add the partitions just fine but when I try to add them to a disk my ManagementObjectSearch just grabs all partitions from all drives. I want to narrow down my search so that when I'm searching for partitions on, let's say, the drive that the OS is on, I want the basic GPT partitions and if I'm searching for partitions on a data drive, I want the one partition that would likely be located on that drive. (Sorry if that did not make much sense).

I have tried a straight query for the partitions, but it appears that my ManagementObjectSearch queries all partitions between both drives, not just the drive I want to search for.

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computer.Name + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk", computer.Options);
        scope.Connect();

        foreach (ComputerDisk disk in computer.DiskList)
        {
            try
            {
                disk.PartitionList = new List<DiskPartition>();
                MessageBox.Show("Disk Name: " + disk.Name);

                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk ");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

                ManagementObjectCollection obj = searcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject os in obj)
                {
                    DiskPartition partition = new DiskPartition();

                    UInt64 fS = (UInt64)os.Properties["FreeSpace"].Value / 1000000000;
                    UInt64 tS = (UInt64)os.Properties["Size"].Value / 1000000000;

                    partition.FreeSpace = fS;
                    partition.TotalSpace = tS;
                    partition.PercentFreeSpace = Convert.ToDouble(partition.FreeSpace / partition.TotalSpace);

                    partition.PartitionName = Convert.ToString(os.Properties["Name"].Value);
                    partition.FileSystem = Convert.ToString(os.Properties["FileSystem"].Value);

                    if (!disk.PartitionList.Contains(partition))
                    {
                        disk.PartitionList.Add(partition);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

At this point I expect all partitions to be found when I run the query, but basically I want to query only partitions on the disk in question. The way my code is set up, I have a computer object that holds a list of disk objects, with each disk object holding a list of DiskPartition objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding the logical disk information and disk partition information separately and only once, not tying that information to each disk drive it was found on. The reason for this is because there is only one property that two of those three classes have in common: win32_logicaldisk.diskindex and win32_diskdrive.index. If there was a property that tied the disk partition and logical disk classes together I would have found a way to ensure that only relevant information for each disk was added only to that disk, not other disks. But, alas, from what I've found there was no property that I could find to relate all these classes. What I implemented was a computer class that housed all the information regarding disks, partitions, and logical disks. This way, for every computer, I can list what partitions were found, their index, what disks are there, and just by visual I can see which disk the partition belongs to. Not the best system but the only one I could find that sort of gave me the solution I was looking for.